# Cron Expression to execute cron triggers on every week at 3 pm and start time from 5th April 2012

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression, crontrigger

I am in need to create a cron triggers expression which should fire on every week at 3 pm and start time from 5th April 2012.

Please note i am using CronTriggerImpl

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By *every week* do you mean *weekly*? Using Quartz 2 API:

```
import org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder.*;

MutableTrigger trigger = weeklyOnDayAndHourAndMinute(Calendar.THURSDAY, 15, 0).build()
trigger.setStartTime(new GregorianCalendar(2012, Calendar.APRIL, 5));
```

This will run the trigger every week on Thursday, 15:00, starting from April 5th.

Comment: actully i am looking the answer for dotnet and i think the given answer above is applicable in the Java.

Comment: @user1301587: so please tag your question appropriately, there is absolutely no mention about .NET there.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively use a cron expression such as "0 0 15 * * THU" and set the start time to a date in the future.